# What is the regex to find lines WITHOUT a line break

Tags: regex, subtitle

I'm using SubtitleEdit and I'd like to locate all the lines that do not contain a line break.

Because lines containing a line break indicates they are bilingual, which I want.

But those that do not have line breaks are mono-lingual, and I'd like to quickly locate them all and delete them. TIA!

Alternatively, if there is a regex expression that can find lines which do not contain any English characters, that would also work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'line break'? `\r\n`  sequence or html `<br>` or what?

Comment: Sorry should've clarified, `<br>`

Comment: Give some examples of input and what should match and what should not match. How do you define 'a line'?

Comment: Please take a look at the screenshot in my comment below, thank you.

Comment: Come on, look at the text, it contains `<br />` NOT `<br>`! The space and the slash do of course also matter.

Comment: I don't think it does though, because what it shows there is artificial: https://i.imgur.com/KlckO6T.png I found out that it doesn't even matter what I put in between the < >, the result is the same ➜ https://i.imgur.com/VkXsDom.png ➜ https://i.imgur.com/N8iS1oB.png

Comment: There is some info here about new line in SubtitleEdit, but it's a lil beyond me... https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/issues/3221

Comment: Ok, weird newline handling by that editor, but having read that Github article, try: `(?=.*\r?\n)`

Comment: Sorry, I meant: `(?!.*\r?\n).*`

Comment: That's actually pretty close. It removes Line 2 which is great. But it's also removing the part of Line 1 that is after the newline. https://i.imgur.com/g3BHAsH.png Basically I'm wanting to remove all the lines which are monolingual. And keep the bilingual lines as they are. Since all the bilingual lines have newline, that's what is differentiating them.

Comment: BTW, is there a regex expression that can find lines which do not contain any English characters? That would also work to quickly identify all the monolingual lines (assuming the monolingual lines are in Chinese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion here was caused by 2 facts:

1. What `SubtitleEdit` calls `a line` is actually a multiline, containing
   newlines.
2. The newline displayed is not the one used internally (so it would never match `<br>`).

**Solution 1:**

Now that we have found out it uses either `\r\n` or just `\n`, we can write a regex:

`(?-m)^(?!.*\r?\n)[\s\S]*$`

**Explanation**:

`(?-m)` - turn off the `multiline` option (which is otherwise enabled).

`^` - match from start of text

`(?!.*\r?\n)` - `negative look ahead` for zero or more of any characters followed by `newline` character(s) - (=Contains)

`[\s\S]*$` - match zero or more of `ANY` character (including newline) - will match the rest of text.

In short: If we don't find `newline` characters, match everything.

Now `replace` with an empty string.

**Solution 2:**

If you want to match lines that doesn't have any English characters, you can use this:

`(?-m)^(?![\s\S]*[a-zA-Z])[\s\S]*$`

**Explanation**:

`(?-m)` - turn off the `multiline` option (which is otherwise enabled).

`^` - match from start of text

`(?![\s\S]*[a-zA-Z])` - `negative look ahead` for `ANY` characters followed by an English character.

`[\s\S]*$` - match zero or more of `ANY` character (including newline) - will match the rest of text.

In short: If we don't find an English character, match everything.

Now `replace` with an empty string.

Comment: Both regex worked perfect as described. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry, could you give the regex for "If we find ONLY English characters, match everything." (including symbols like ! or ? that are part of normal English sentences)

Answer (score 1):

You should use regex assert. Given test lines:

```
something_1
some<br>thing_2
something_3<br>
<br>something_4
something_5
```

This is an expression that will match lines 1 and 5

```
^(?!.*<br>).*$
```

In this regular expression we have the negative lookahead assertion **(?!.*<br>)** that allows us to define what line is suitable for us

Comment: I tried using ^(?!.*<br>).*$ but it finds everything that is not <br>
I only want it to find the lines which don't contain <br>
A screenshot to make it clearer what I mean: https://i.imgur.com/XsD72Se.png
So here I need it to find LINE 4 and replace it with nothing. But instead it's sort of doing the opposite.

Comment: Let me correct myself, it IS indeed working for LINE 4, because as you can see in the "after" column, it becomes blank. Very good. But the problem is that it's also replacing all the texts in all the other lines (sans <br>), but I don't want that.

Comment: Did you try **^(?!.*<br />).*$** expression?

Comment: Yes I did, same result. I think it is because what it shows there as new line is artificial: https://i.imgur.com/KlckO6T.png I found out that it doesn't even matter what I put in between the < >, the result is the same ➜ https://i.imgur.com/VkXsDom.png ➜ https://i.imgur.com/N8iS1oB.png

Comment: There is some info here about new line in SubtitleEdit, but it's a lil beyond me... https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/issues/3221